# Java rotating characters with a negative input

Tags: java

We have been working on an issue for a little while now and cannot seem to figure it out. It was suggested I post a new question with this information. I have a method that rotates characters in a string for encryption. The user chooses the amount of the shift and the direction of the shift. Direction `1` is working great, direction `2` however is not. Output for direction 1 for string `ABCD` comes out as `BDFH` which is what I want (the shift amount changes after each letter), however direction 1 output for `ABCD` is coming out as `ZZZZ`

Can anyone tell why the shift is not working properly? Have been working on this one for days and it's driving me mad! Thank you for any help.

Overloaded methods:

```
public static String rotate(String userString, int shiftValue, int shiftDirection) {
    if (shiftDirection == 1) {
        return rotate(userString, shiftValue);
    }
    else if (shiftDirection == 2) {
        return rotate(userString, -shiftValue);
    }
    else {
        return "This is not a valid way to shift your message.";
    }
}

public static String rotate(String userString, int shiftValue) {
   StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
   int myShift = shiftValue % 26 + 26;
   for (char i : userString.toCharArray()) {
       if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + myShift) % 26 ));
            } else {
                encoded.append((char) ('a' + (i - 'a' + myShift) % 26 ));
            }
        } else {
            encoded.append(i);
        }
        myShift = (myShift + shiftValue) % 26;
    }
    return encoded.toString();
}
```

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc `shiftDirection` is the direction to shift the message, i.e. shift forward by `shiftValue` (`shiftDirection` = 1) or shift backward by `shiftValue` (`shiftDirection` = 2).

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc I think I know what you are saying, but that's how the OP wants it. BTW, I think you misunderstood his question. He doesn't want to rotate the message as in `ABCD` => `BCDA`. He is doing a variation of a cryptographic code where each letter is shifted. He just decided to call the shifting function `rotate`.

Comment: @mmking You're correct, I misunderstood.

Comment: Correct @mmking the order of things is exactly the way I want it, however it just will not work going in the opposite direction

Comment: What is the expected output of shift direction 2 with input "ABCD"?

Comment: For `-1` on `ABCD` , are you expecting `ZXVT`?

Comment: For direction 2 it would produce `YXWV` because each time its shift a letter, the `shiftValue` is added to myshift. So after testing some more, the method is working EXCEPT when the shift value is 1. Only when direction is 2 and shift value is 1 does this program not work! So why is 1 causing this to happen??

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc yes! It is only when I use 1 for the value that the program is not working. A shift of 2 or higher produces the results, a shift of 1 produces `ZZZZ`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The irony here is that, believe it or not, there is nothing wrong with your code.  "ABCD" should produce "ZZZZ" when shifted in the opposite direction.  To see this, use "ZZZZ" as your input.  Shifting it with direction 1 will produce "ABCD".

To elaborate:

```
A will be shifted 1 to Z
B will be shifted 2, which is also Z
C will be shifted 3, which is also Z
D will be shifted 4, which is also Z
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Can it truly be that simple!? This whole time! I believe you are right, the method has been okay this whole time! Thank you @pathfinderelite

Comment: I had just come to the same conclusion. Nice, @pathfinderelite!